# VB - change property of all checkboxes

Tags: vba, checkbox, wildcard

I am very naive with programming in general and Visual Basic in particular.

My question sounds really stupid and irrelevant, but I have been struggling with it since a couple of hours.

I am writing a survey using Microsoft Office and the Visual Basic environment to take advantage of functions like check-box, buttons etc .

I was wondering whether there is way to change all at once a property of all my check-boxes (e.g. the font color)?
That is, if I press the button X all the check-boxes turn red (this is a stupid example, is a bit more complicated). I know I have to address the field .ForeColor but I do not know whether is possible to change it for all the check-boxes at the same time (and they're really a lot, so changing the property one by one or creating manually an array is out of question :p ).

My check-boxes are named Q1A, Q1B, Q1C, Q2A, Q2B ...Is there a way to use a wildcard like "*", e.g. Q*.ForeColor = &HFF& ?, in a way to apply these properties to all the check-boxes which name starts with  "Q"?

I hope I made myself clear,
thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what application you are using (Word, Excel, Access?), but generally you can loop through the controls....For instance in Access, it would be "For each ctl In Me.Controls" where ctl is declared as a Variant. Then you can check the type of the control using "if ctl.controltype = acCheckBox Then" and then further check the name of the checkbox using "if left(ctl.name, 1) = "Q" Then"....For further assistance, please provide your code and application....

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using MS Word.  
I am trying to do the following
If Q1A.Value = False And Q1B.Value = False And Q1C.Value = False Then
Check = MsgBox(".........")
Q1A.ForeColor = &HFF&
Q1B.ForeColor = &HFF&
Q1C.ForeColor = &HFF&

else 
Check = MsgBox("....")
Q1A.ForeColor = &H0&
Q1B.ForeColor = &H0&
Q1C.ForeColor = &H0&

But keep in mind I have tens of checkboxes and I would like to find an easier way to change the property to all of them. 

I will try to follow your suggestion anyway

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through all the controls in the word doc, and update the checkboxes with names begining with "Q" as desired.  Note that this is for ActiveX checkboxes, which I'm pretty sure are what you are using.

```
Public Sub Testsub()

Dim control As Object

If Me.QA1.Value = False and Q1B.Value = False And Q1C.Value = False Then 
     Check = MsgBox(".........") 
     For Each control In Me.InlineShapes
          If control.OLEFormat.ClassType = "Forms.CheckBox.1" Then 
          'check if object is a checkbox
              If Left(control.OLEFormat.Object.Name, 1) = "Q" Then
              'check if checkbox name starts with "Q", then format checkbox
                   control.OLEFormat.Object.Value = True
                   control.oleformat.object.forecolor = &HFF&
                   'add anything else you want to do to each checkbox here
              End If
          End If


     Next control
ElseIf Me.QA1.value................
   'Any other criteria you want to checkfor, use same loop to set the checkboxes.

End If

End Sub
```